# VueJS can't bind input to properties generated in beforeMount hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding

I'm trying to generate a nested series of objects in a `beforeMount` hook.
Any data binding I try to enforce between inputs doesn't work. There are no errors.

Here is a simple version of what I'm doing which encapsulates the problem.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    data () {return {
    multi: {}, 
    ids: ["eaf", "6ef", "3ey"]
  }},
  beforeMount () {
    this.ids.forEach(i=> {
     this.multi[i] = {
       name: "",
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  
  <div id="group" v-for="(i, index) in ids">
    <p>Group {{i}}</p>
    <p>{{multi[i].name}}</p>
    
    <input type="text" v-model="multi[i].name">
  </div>
</div>
```

The v-model bind does NOT work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue does not detect new props in already reactive objects. You should use Vue.$set or create the **multi** object with all necessary props beforehand. See [Detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

Comment: Ooooh I see.. damn I thought as much as well.
The object I'm creating is quite large and given the context, I can't know ahead of time how large the object will be or what properties it will contain.

I will look into vue set. Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

Populating an object doesn't require multiple calls to `$set`.  You can do this too:

```
beforeMount () {
    const multi = {};
    this.ids.forEach(i=> {
        multi[i] = {
          name: "",
        }
    })
    this.multi = multi;
}
```

This works because instead of setting properties on `this.multi`, you create a new object and set the existing data property to it.  Vue can detect this change.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't know that. 
Thank you very much for sharing that.

Comment: You're welcome.  I prefer using `$set` as little as possible, and it isn't used in Vue 3. 
 Plus, setting the data directly also allows the object to be created somewhere else (like an outside API) without needing to import Vue and use `Vue.set`.